# How to use ListAdapter in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, listadapter

I am Trying to Display `IP Address` in a `ListView`.In my code,iam displaying the Ip addresses in a `TextView`.Now i am trying to set a ListAdapter to display the Contents of the `ArrayList`.I don't know where can i insert the List adapter.I tried in the `onPostExecute` But it returned a Error on the `ListAdapter` Parameter

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ClientScanResult>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clients));
```

I already used setText & append to display in TextView.But how to Display the Values in ListAdapter ??

**connect.java**

```
public class connect extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
WifiApManager wifiApManager;
TextView tv;
Button ipscan;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect);
    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.iptv);
    ipscan=(Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
    ipscan.setOnClickListener(this);  
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


}
class scan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<ClientScanResult>>{ 
    public Context context;
    ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients= new  ArrayList<ClientScanResult>();
    public scan(Context c)  // constructor to take Context
    {
        context = c;   // Initialize your Context variable
    }

    protected ArrayList<ClientScanResult> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        wifiApManager = new WifiApManager(context);  // use the variable here
        return wifiApManager.getClientList(false);

    }

protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ClientScanResult> clients){

//tv.setText("WifiApState: " + wifiApManager.getWifiApState() + "\n\n");
    //tv.append("Clients: \n");
for (ClientScanResult clientScanResult : clients) //showin error in clients
    {
        //tv.append("####################\n");
       // tv.append("IpAddr: " + clientScanResult.getIpAddr() + "\n");
        // tv.append("Device: " + clientScanResult.getDevice() + "\n");
       // tv.append("HWAddr: " + clientScanResult.getHWAddr() + "\n");
       // tv.append("isReachable: " + clientScanResult.isReachable()+ "\n");
    }
}
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Click Action...
    scan myScan = new scan(this); // pass the context to the constructor
    myScan.execute();
}
}
```

NOTE:
I Commented the Lines which i used to display the values in TextView.

Comment: Don't keep a hard reference to a Context inside a task that can take longer to process than the lifetime of that Context - this is probably the most frequent cause of memory issues on Android. As a non-static inner class, `scan` has this reference anyway, but you don't want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I tried in the onPostExecute But it returned a Error on the ListAdapter Parameter
```

Then

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<ClientScanResult>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clients));
```

But your Activity does not extend `ListActivity`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

`setListAdapter` is a method of `ListActivity`.

Replace `this` by `connect.this`.

Also follow naming conventions. Name you class like Connect(C caps)

```
ListView lv; // declare as isntance variable
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.connect);
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list); // initialize
```

In `onPostExecute`

```
ArrayAdapter<ClientScanResult> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<ClientScanResult>(connect.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, clients)
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: @ArulNadhan did i mention anything about it. You are referring to the layout in the android layout package

Comment: @ArulNadhan nope. If you read the docs you should know the parameters to be passed to the constructor of `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: I have a ListView whose id is list.But it is showing a Error in Log .01-02 23:11:13.370: E/AndroidRuntime(14079): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arul.remoteit/com.arul.remoteit.connect}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: @ArulNadhan what does your `Activity` extend??

Comment: public class connect extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener

Comment: @ArulNadhan perfect your code in the post is not right. Now show me the xml layout and read topi screen layout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html